# Calculating mean value using ArcPy Statistics_analysis, in_memory

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

So, among the selected values want to calculate median value.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"Database Connections\local.sde"
pLoc = "local.DBO.Parcels"
luLoc = "local.DBO.Land_Use"
luFields = ["MedYrBlt","MedVal","OCCount"]
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(pLoc,"cities_lyr")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("cities_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", "YrBlt > 1000")
```

from selected cities_lyr want to calculate mean value field from YrBlt

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(luLoc, ["OID@", "SHAPE@", luFields[0], luFields[1], luFields[2]]) as cursor:
   for row in cursor:
      if arcpy.Exists('in_memory/stats'):
        arcpy.Delete_management(r'in_memory/stats')
      arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('cities_lyr', select_features = row[1])
      arcpy.Statistics_analysis('cities_lyr', 'in_memory/stats','YrBlt MEAN','OBJECTID')
```

Here comes a question:
I just want to see the mean value, how can I do that?

---

```
luFields = ["MedYrBlt","MedVal","OCCount"]
```

are going to be used later not important for now.

Comment: Just in case you are not aware of it there is a [gis.se] Stack Exchange with MANY ArcPy questions already answered on it.

Answer (score 2):

Append values to an empty array and then calculate mean of that array. For example:

```
# Create array & cycle through years, append values to array
yrArray =[]
for row in cursor:
    val = getValue("yrBlt")
    yrArray.append(val)

#get sum of all values in array
x = 0
for i in yrArray: 
    x += i

#get average by dividing above sum by the length of the array. 
meanYrBlt = x / len(yrArray)
```

On another note it may be beneficial to separate these processes out into their own classes. For example:

```
class arrayAvg: 
    def __init__(self,array):
        x = 0
        for i in array:
            x += 1
        arrayLength = len(array)
        arrayAvg = x/arrayLength
        self.avg = arrayAvg
        self.count = arrayLength
```

This way you can reuse the code by calling:

```
yrBltAvg = arrayAvg(yrArray)
avg = yrBltAvg.avg #returns average
count = yrBltAvg.count #returns count
```

The second portion is unnecessary, but allows you to take advantage of object oriented programming, and you can expand upon that throughout the program.